# Connection failure when making HTTP request from ASP .NET MVC (possible IIS issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to consume JSON file from an external service in the Controller and trying to output it to the View. I am using the RestSharp API to perform the call and return a list of projects.

```
public virtual ActionResult Details()
{
var client = new RestClient("http://192.0.2.0/service");
var request = new RestRequest("/api/Project/{userId}/{projectId}", Method.GET);
request.AddUrlSegment("ownerOrgId", "42");
request.AddUrlSegment("studyId", "57);

var response = client.Execute<List<Project>>(request);
if (response.Data == null)
    throw new Exception("Exception occurred connecting to services.", response.ErrorException);

return View(response.Data);
}
```

Now, calling the Rest API works from console, IE, Chrome and if the MVC application is hosted locally using IIS Express.

But when I call it from the MVC application hosted using IIS 7.5, I get the following error:-

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.0.2.0:80

Could anyone tell me what could be done to fix this?

Comment: Replaced studyId with projectId. Still the same error.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall? Also, I assume 192.0.2.0 is not the network identifier for your subnet? ie. that you have 192.0.0.0/8 as a network for instance? Or is 192.0.2.0 the very first ip address of your subnet? It is not a good idea to use the .0 address corresponding to the subnet identifier.

Comment: 192.0.2.0 is a sample IP address. I am sorry for the confusion. As mentioned, I am getting this code snippet to work from console.